# Call AngularJS from other scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

application. Now i want to implement an dynamic menu with AngularJS. Therefore i need to change variables in the AngularJS application from my existing application.

I'm trying with this example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="myApp">

  First Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
  <br>
  <br>Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
  <button ng-click="resetName()">hi</button>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  $scope.resetName = function() {
    $scope.firstName = "John1";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe1";
  }
});

</script>

<button onclick="angular.element('#myApp').scope().resetName(); angular.element('#myApp').scope().apply();">extern</button>
```

what would be the correct way to call the "resetName()" function from an external script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just attach a selector to your DOM element where your controller is defined. like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="myCtrl">
```

and from anywhere you can call this controller function like

```
angular.element('#myCtrl').scope().resetName()
```

OR

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myCtrl')).scope().resetName()
```

In some case you need to modify a object value of controller you can do it in simple way. Just use

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myCtrl')).scope().title = 'test';
```

Note : Please don't forget to `apply` the changes because now angular will not trigger `apply` automatically. You need to trigger `apply` manually. Just put below line after updating values in object/s

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myCtrl')).scope().apply();
```

Comment: @wutzebaer -- Along with this, if you ever need to test Angular functions in your console, you can use the above as well `var z = angular.element('#myCtrl').scope(); z.resetName("Test Param");`

Comment: @tymeJV totally agreed (y)

Comment: is it possible to change scope variables like this: angular.element('#topMenu').scope().title = "test"; - i tried but get an error: Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/jqLite/nosel

Comment: Just try `angular.element(document.querySelector('#myCtrl')).scope().title = "test"`;

Comment: i've tried your solution in my snippet above and get the same error, coud you have a look what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please include `jquery.min.js` before `angular.js` and then please let me know are you still getting the same error ?

Comment: i've added jquery to the snipped: same result - just open the js console and hit run - could you provide a running snippet?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the controller function from external script ? I din;t see here your external script code. I've used the  same in one of my app and it worked like a charm.

Comment: i've replaced the snippet by static code... the snipped didn't seem to update correctly

Comment: ok i found the two problems: 1: you have to wait for document.ready before you can access external, 2: the function is called $apply()