# How to get a DOM element by his ID from an angular template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I need to get an element by his ID, but this element is loaded from another html file.

This is my index.html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div ng-include="foo.template"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in myCtrl.js :

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
        title: 'Title',
        template: 'views/myTemplate.html'
    };
    console.log(document.getElementById('test')) // Display null
}]);
```

And myTemplate.html:

```
<div id="test">Check</div>
<script>
    console.log(document.getElementById('test')) // Never execute
</script>
```

**How can I get the DOM element with the ID 'test'?**

FYI, I need to get it for a JS lib to add a custom scrollbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301475/call-angularjs-from-other-scripts/31301533#31301533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> Wraps a raw DOM element or HTML string as a jQuery element.
>
> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('test'));
```

OR

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#test'))
```

**EDIT**

You need to use `$timeout`:
Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout. The fn function is wrapped into a try/catch block and delegates any exceptions to $exceptionHandler service.

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.foo = {
        title: 'Title',
        template: 'views/myTemplate.html'
    };

    $timeout(function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    }, 0);

    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
    // }, 0);
}]);
```

Comment: This is an example that explains how to get element by ID in Angular.js. http://mlen.io/angular-js/get-element-by-id.html

Comment: can you explain why we need to have a setTimeout function in the controller?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin That will hold the execution until previous statements in queue are completed

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery to get the elements and process it.

```
$("#test").html(); will display "Check" in your case.
```

Comment: No `jQuery` is tagged

Comment: Open this plunker link to see a live preview, http://plnkr.co/edit/CBXThWRHdnHwa5RZXD0C?p=preview

Comment: What I'm saying is `jQuery` is not tagged in question, as well not even mentioned in question

Comment: Ok, I just said another way of getting the element.

Answer (score 0):

With angularjs, deal with jQuery to manipulate element is bad especially in controllers (this is the wrong way), it should be managed in directives.

But for your issue, you try to get the element while he's not loaded (async call), so you should write a directive for this element, and in the link function, do whatever you want, cause the element will be loaded.