# Any way to change ngModal value in input field using javascript

Tags: angular

My problem is when I change input field value using javascript, it won't change in `ngModel` value.

For example:

```
//html 
<input type="text" name="date" [(ngModel)]="date">
```

Typescript

```
  var date : any;
    constructor(
            // some code
        ) {
            this.date="10:10:2016";
        }
```

When I console 'date' it will show 10:10:2016

After executing this Javascript code

```
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value = "15:10:2016";
```

text field will change its value, but `ngModel` value won't change

btw I use jQuery datepicker

Comment: Is it banner or date ?

Comment: date sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger an input event on the element so Angular knows that something changed. Look at the answer here: [Change AngularJS input text value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498629/change-angularjs-input-text-value-using-javascript)

Comment: tried $('[name="date"]').keydown(); $('[name="date"]').keyup(); $('[name="date"]').keypress();; $('[name="date"]').blur(); but nothing works

Comment: try $('[name="date"]').trigger("input")

Comment: How are you checking whether ngModel is changing on the backend?

Comment: i use test function on button click to console it 
    testing(){
        console.log(this.date);
    }

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the javascript code in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {  
  let myNewDate= document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value = "15:10:2016";; 
  this.date = myNewDate;
}
```

and assign the value to your `date` variable.

Comment: Thanks , this code works fine . but i use external js (jquery) to assign value to input field and i think i found a solution..

Comment: Use jquery input function  in ngView and assign value of input field value to ngModel now i don't have access to my pc to test this code. Will post solution after testing :) , your answer helped me to solve my problem .. thank you