# How to make the a input field dirty through JavaScript of a angular 1 page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a script/chrome extension to automate a process. I want to change a input field. I tried to do it with changing the value of html input field. But the problem I am facing is I can't make the field dirty which is restricting to make the button enable as field are untouched.

I have tried to make field focus and blur. Not worked.

[Change AngularJS input text value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498629/change-angularjs-input-text-value-using-javascript)
Also tried this one.

The button doesn't get enabled.

Do any body have any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this should work: yourinputelement.focus(); document.execCommand('selectAll', false); document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'your text');

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm
Thank solved my problem ;)

Comment: In angular 1, I create a watch on an model attribute to flip the dirty flag.  I kept a dirty flag global on the page .  Enable/disable button based on dirty flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourinputelement.focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll', false);
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'your text');
```